# Python 3: JSON File Load with Non-ASCII Characters

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

just trying to load this JSON file(with non-ascii characters) as a python dictionary  with Unicode encoding but still getting this error:

return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 90: ordinal not in range(128)

JSON file content = "tooltip":{
        "dxPivotGrid-sortRowBySummary": "Sort\"{0}\"byThisRow",}

```
import sys  
import json

data = []
with open('/Users/myvb/Desktop/Automation/pt-PT.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line.encode('utf-8','replace')))
```

Comment: `json.loads` as an argument encoding. What is real content of the `pt-PT.json` file - are there lines of valid JSON data, or it is one long JSON file? In later case it would be better load directly as a file, not line by line.

Comment: The string you show as JSON file content is not valid JSON, it is only fragment of larger object.

Comment: Tried loading as a file also but same issue and error is shown

Comment: Try to validate the JSON file by some JSON validator first. There are online tools, and some command line ones.

Comment: Check modified question now, it's due to some line in the json file, not sure how to fix it

Comment: Your JSON snippet in your question has once comma extra, which makes it invalid JSON. It shall read `{ "dxPivotGrid-sortRowBySummary": "Sort\"{0}\"byThisRow"}` - note, that the last `,` was removed.

Comment: it's a big file with some 40K lines, so that comma may be for the next key

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have several problems as near as I can tell. First, is the file encoding. When you open a file without specifying an encoding, the file is opened with whatever `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` is. Since that may vary (especially on Windows machines) its a good idea to explicitly use `encoding="utf-8"` for most json files. Because of your error message, I suspect that the file was opened with an `ascii` encoding.

Next, the file is decoded from utf-8 into python strings as it is read by the file system object. The utf-8 line has already been decoded to a string and is already ready for json to read. When you do `line.encode('utf-8','replace')`, you encode the line back into a `bytes` object which the json `loads` (that is, "load string") can't handle.

Finally, `"tooltip":{ "navbar":"Operações de grupo"}` isn't valid json, but it does look like one line of a pretty-printed json file containing a single json object. My guess is that you should read the entire file as 1 json object.

Putting it all together you get:

```
import json

with open('/Users/myvb/Desktop/Automation/pt-PT.json', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

From its name, its possible that this file is encoded as a Windows Portugese code page. If so, the `"cp860"` encoding may work better.

Comment: it's not because of portugese content but due to JSON file content = "tooltip":{ "dxPivotGrid-sortRowBySummary": "Sort\"{0}\"byThisRow",}

Comment: I see you've changed the string causing problems in your question from one that has non-ascii characters. The new string doesn't contain an 0xc3 utf-8 encoding byte so I don't see how it can produce the "can't decode byte 0xc3" error. Regardless, that string isn't valid JSON but does look like a fragment of valid JSON. Are you saying that the entire file contains just that one line?

Comment: This was a life saver when having problems with a script on a Chinese colleague's Windows machine that was fine on Macs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what worked for me was creating a regular expression, and parsing every line from the json file:

```
REGEXP = '[^A-Za-z0-9\'\:\.\;\-\?\!]+'
new_file_line = re.sub(REGEXP, ' ', old_file_line).strip()
```

Comment: This strips all non-English characters which is likely not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Having a file with content similar to yours I can read the file in one simple shot:

```
>>> import json
>>> fname = "data.json"
>>> with open(fname) as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
...
>>> data
{'tooltip': {'navbar': 'Operações de grupo'}}
```

Comment: after lot of analysis i found, it's giving this error because of this data in the json file:

Comment: "dxPivotGrid-sortRowBySummary": "Sort\"{0}\"byThisRow",

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read each line. You have two options:

```
import sys  
import json

data = []
with open('/Users/myvb/Desktop/Automation/pt-PT.json') as f:
    data.append(json.load(f))
```

Or, you can load all lines and pass them to the json module:

```
import sys  
import json

data = []
with open('/Users/myvb/Desktop/Automation/pt-PT.json') as f:
    data.append(json.loads(''.join(f.readlines())))
```

Obviously, the first suggestion is the best.